# Как вытащить значение из 2-х разных Json файлов?

Tags: php, html, json, api, json-encode

Есть код:

```
    <?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=MOW&token=xxxxxxx&limit=10");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: xxxxxx"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json=json_decode($response,true);
?>
<?php 
$products=json_decode($response,true);

foreach ($products as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<table class='mytable'><hr>";
     foreach ($value as $k=> $v) {
           echo "<tr><td><br>".$k."</td><td></td></tr>";
           foreach ($v as $g=> $l) { 
                $g=str_replace ('price','цена',$g); 
                     $g=str_replace ('airline','авиакомпания',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('origin','город вылета',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('destination','город прилета',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('transfers','кол-во пересадок',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('flight_number','номер рейса',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('departure_at','дата вылета',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('return_at','дата возвращения',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('expires_at','Срок истечения актуальности цены',$g);

                     echo "<tr><td>".$g."</td><td>".$l."</td></tr>";
            } 
     }
     echo "</table>";  
}

?>
```

Есть Json файлы, вот они:
Данные о странах в json : `api.travelpayouts.com/data/countries.json`
Данные о городах в json формате: `api.travelpayouts.com/data/cities.json`
Данные об аэропортах в json формате: `api.travelpayouts.com/data/airports.json`
Данные об авиакомпаниях в json формате: `api.travelpayouts.com/data/airlines.json`

Мне нужно, чтобы из Json заменялись значения:
`'airline', 'origin', 'destination'`,
Вот как выглядит таблица сейчас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Покажите по возможности на примере моего кода.

По API получаю вот такой ответ:

```
{"success": true, "data": [{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"PEN","destination":"KUL","depart_date":"2016-04-11","return_date":"2016-04-14","number_of_changes":0,"value":983,"found_at":"2016-01-03T18:33:11+04:00","distance":286,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"UBP","destination":"BKK","depart_date":"2016-07-09","return_date":"2016-07-11","number_of_changes":0,"value":1178,"found_at":"2016-01-03T21:00:12+04:00","distance":502,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"KUL","destination":"KBR","depart_date":"2016-03-23","return_date":"2016-03-31","number_of_changes":0,"value":1295,"found_at":"2016-01-03T22:58:02+04:00","distance":343,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"KUL","destination":"PEN","depart_date":"2016-03-22","return_date":"2016-03-27","number_of_changes":0,"value":1492,"found_at":"2016-01-02T04:15:51+04:00","distance":286,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"BKK","destination":"CNX","depart_date":"2016-05-17","return_date":"2016-05-17","number_of_changes":0,"value":1555,"found_at":"2016-01-03T23:40:36+04:00","distance":583,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"DUS","destination":"ROM","depart_date":"2016-01-28","return_date":"2016-02-02","number_of_changes":0,"value":1580,"found_at":"2016-01-03T02:56:18+04:00","distance":1125,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"NNT","destination":"BKK","depart_date":"2016-06-24","return_date":"2016-06-28","number_of_changes":0,"value":1584,"found_at":"2016-01-03T20:24:11+04:00","distance":565,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"BKK","destination":"UTH","depart_date":"2016-05-28","return_date":"2016-05-30","number_of_changes":0,"value":1590,"found_at":"2016-01-03T21:52:52+04:00","distance":476,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"BLQ","destination":"BUH","depart_date":"2016-01-29","return_date":"2016-02-03","number_of_changes":0,"value":1590,"found_at":"2016-01-03T02:31:12+04:00","distance":1169,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"SUF","destination":"ROM","depart_date":"2016-03-19","return_date":"2016-03-23","number_of_changes":0,"value":1590,"found_at":"2016-01-03T20:13:57+04:00","distance":458,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"DUB","destination":"LON","depart_date":"2016-02-06","return_date":"2016-02-08","number_of_changes":0,"value":1591,"found_at":"2016-01-03T03:16:06+04:00","distance":477,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"DUB","destination":"MAN","depart_date":"2016-01-23","return_date":"2016-02-01","number_of_changes":0,"value":1591,"found_at":"2016-01-03T14:48:54+04:00","distance":265,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"DUB","destination":"NCL","depart_date":"2016-02-03","return_date":"2016-02-09","number_of_changes":0,"value":1591,"found_at":"2016-01-02T01:08:07+04:00","distance":344,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"BKK","destination":"KBV","depart_date":"2016-11-23","return_date":"2016-11-28","number_of_changes":0,"value":1625,"found_at":"2016-01-02T23:07:24+04:00","distance":646,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"LED","destination":"PKV","depart_date":"2016-01-15","return_date":"2016-01-16","number_of_changes":0,"value":1655,"found_at":"2016-01-03T11:12:47+04:00","distance":262,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"KUL","destination":"JHB","depart_date":"2016-02-07","return_date":"2016-02-11","number_of_changes":0,"value":1662,"found_at":"2016-01-03T07:33:14+04:00","distance":276,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"TGG","destination":"KUL","depart_date":"2016-02-20","return_date":"2016-02-27","number_of_changes":0,"value":1662,"found_at":"2016-01-03T12:44:59+04:00","distance":294,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"CGN","destination":"BER","depart_date":"2016-01-20","return_date":"2016-01-22","number_of_changes":0,"value":1677,"found_at":"2016-01-03T22:00:07+04:00","distance":477,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"CGN","destination":"LON","depart_date":"2016-02-10","return_date":"2016-02-11","number_of_changes":0,"value":1678,"found_at":"2016-01-02T04:03:01+04:00","distance":484,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"KUL","destination":"LGK","depart_date":"2016-03-01","return_date":"2016-03-08","number_of_changes":0,"value":1684,"found_at":"2016-01-03T21:55:01+04:00","distance":417,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"HDY","destination":"BKK","depart_date":"2016-11-16","return_date":"2016-11-19","number_of_changes":0,"value":1726,"found_at":"2016-01-03T10:56:00+04:00","distance":754,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"VVO","destination":"KVR","depart_date":"2016-01-10","return_date":"2016-01-17","number_of_changes":0,"value":1735,"found_at":"2016-01-03T05:09:51+04:00","distance":252,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"BRU","destination":"CPH","depart_date":"2016-02-04","return_date":"2016-02-09","number_of_changes":0,"value":1750,"found_at":"2016-01-02T21:00:58+04:00","distance":767,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"BUH","destination":"MIL","depart_date":"2016-02-02","return_date":"2016-02-09","number_of_changes":0,"value":1750,"found_at":"2016-01-03T01:14:21+04:00","distance":1333,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"WAW","destination":"CGN","depart_date":"2016-01-23","return_date":"2016-01-24","number_of_changes":0,"value":1750,"found_at":"2016-01-03T00:56:57+04:00","distance":977,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"MIL","destination":"BUH","depart_date":"2016-02-13","return_date":"2016-02-14","number_of_changes":0,"value":1752,"found_at":"2016-01-03T23:50:37+04:00","distance":1333,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"IST","destination":"AYT","depart_date":"2016-06-06","return_date":"2016-06-29","number_of_changes":0,"value":1793,"found_at":"2016-01-03T12:23:11+04:00","distance":484,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"GDN","destination":"STO","depart_date":"2016-01-22","return_date":"2016-01-24","number_of_changes":0,"value":1802,"found_at":"2016-01-03T23:41:01+04:00","distance":551,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"ATH","destination":"RHO","depart_date":"2016-02-08","return_date":"2016-02-15","number_of_changes":0,"value":1823,"found_at":"2016-01-03T05:29:12+04:00","distance":404,"actual":true},{"show_to_affiliates":false,"trip_class":0,"origin":"BRU","destination":"BUD","depart_date":"2016-02-16","return_date":"2016-03-16","number_of_changes":0,"value":1823,"found_at":"2016-01-03T07:00:43+04:00","distance":1129,"actual":true}]}
```

Comment: така вчем проблема? вм не хочется копатьяс в больших текстовых файлах, чтоб определить пути?

Comment: Я привел пример ответа Апи. Код подправить под это дело сам не смогу, так как собирал его частями. И плохо в этом понимаю.

Comment: Интересно, а что вы со всем этим потом будете делать, плохо понимая в этом. У вас даже текущий код мягко говоря не рассчитан на тот json который вы пытаетесь обработать. Он генерит кучу пустых таблиц в начале и дополнительно к этому выдает предупреждения, натыкаясь на несовместимые типы данных. И как к вам в программу попадут другие json вы уже подумали ? просто в текстовых переменных их зададите ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю для кого старался, но примерно выглядит вот так (код для примера):

```
<?php

$map = function($array, $from, $to){
    $result = [];
    if(!empty($array) && is_array($array)){
        foreach ($array as $element) {
            $key = $element[$from]?:null;
            $value = $element[$to]?:null;
            if($key && $value){
                $result[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
};

$airlines = $map(json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/airlines.json'), true), 'iata', 'name');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/city-directions?origin=MOW&token=хххххх&limit=10");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: ххххххх"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$products=json_decode($response,true);

$replace_pairs=[
    'price' => 'цена',
    'airline'=>'авиакомпания',
    'origin'=>'город вылета',
    'destination'=>'город прилета',
    'transfers'=>'кол-во пересадок',
    'flight_number'=>'номер рейса',
    'departure_at'=>'дата вылета',
    'return_at'=>'дата возвращения',
    'expires_at'=>'Срок истечения актуальности цены'
];


$replace_value = function($key, $val) use ($airlines){
    $response = $val;
    switch($key){
        case 'airline':
            $response = $airlines[$val];
            break;
    }
    return $response;
}

?>

<?php if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])){?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><?php echo $key?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php if(!empty($data && is_array($data))){?>
            <?php foreach ($data as $field=> $val) {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo strtr($field, $replace_pairs);?></td>
                <td><?php echo $replace_value($field, $val);?></td>
            </tr>
            <?}?>
        <?php }?>
    <?}?>
</table>
<?php }?>
```

Т.к. понятия не имею к каким файлам относятся поля 'origin', 'destination', и желания дальше разбираться нет, то не добавлял, но думаю мысль ясна.
Хоть немного организуйте свой код, что бы хотя бы вы понимали что там происходит. Скачайте/откройте json файлы и смотрите их структуру, найдите хотя бы одно требуемое значение, и посмотрите как до него до браться, поэкспериментируйте уже в самом коде, выводите итерации, используете методы дебага что бы понять что там вам выводится/отдается, но судя по всему стоит изначально с массивами разобраться, как они строятся/обрабатываются и т.д.

P.S. Подозреваю что само апи умеет настраиваться и отдавать то что необходимо сразу, но не уверен.

Comment: Вот это вы поработали! Спасибо большущее, сейчас попробую

Comment: Все работает замечательно, спасибо, с большим уважением к ВАМ!

Comment: Простите за наглость, а как мне от сюда http://api.travelpayouts.com/data/cities.json Достать destination

Comment: @Arcadiy Не забудьте, что я говорил вам в прошлый раз, когда вы задавали этот вопрос. Скачайте куда нибудь ваши json. У вас справочник городов 2.5Mb и качать его при каждом запуске php заново в корне не верно. Ну и данный код вы конечно должны будете сильно доработать, больше чем у половины АК из справочника кода IATA нет, только икао. Я кстати справочник городов смотрел, там надо из подмассива доставать русское наименование и если его нет брать латинское. И для скорости работы куда то сохранить результат разбора, что бы на лету кучу преобразований не делать

Comment: Да, я закачаю его к себе. Спасибо за совет.

Comment: @Arcadiy Я города так разбирал: `$cit=json_decode(file_get_contents("cities.json"));
$cities=array();
foreach($cit as $val)
{
 if(property_exists($val->name_translations,"ru")) $cities[$val->code]=$val->name_translations->ru;
 else $cities[$val->code]=$val->name;
}
` жаль тут переводов кареток в коде нет, думаю разберетесь. И справочник АК я бы то же на вашем месте по аналогии разбирал, что бы брать нужные коды икао/иата. В `$cities` массив имен городов с доступом по коду - т.е. в таком же виде как АК в данном ответе

Comment: Попробовал как Вы написали, но почему-то город не меняется

Comment: Ну я только подготовку массива для замены дал. А в свой код использование сами встраивайте. Можете print_r($cities) сделать - посмотреть правильно ли справочник выглядит. И вы файл кстати загрузили к себе, я же в примере его уже по url беру а из каталога со скриптом.

Comment: @Arcadiy Вам там даже почву подготовили `case` добавить и имя массива поменять, ну и массив еще один в `use` указать, что бы функция его увидила

Comment: Спасибо, пробую но как был код города так он почему-то и остается

Comment: Вот так делаю $replace_value = function($key, $val) use ($cit, $airlines){
    $response = $val;
    switch($key){case 'origin':
            $response = $cit[$val];
        case 'airline':
            $response = $airlines[$val];
            break;
    }
    return $response;
}

?>

Comment: @Arcadiy Нужен не `$cit`, а `$cities`. Потому как в `$cit` был изначальный, не конвертированный json. А вообще я бы сохранил этот $cities опять в виде json и просто подгружал бы его уже готовым, что бы каждый раз не преобразовывать

Comment: Все прекрасно заработало, было дело в моей безграммотности в данном вопроосе. Большущее вам спасибо!